# Como instalar aplicativos .apk via adb?

Tags: android

Preciso de ajuda, gostaria de entender como usar o CMD para isso e porque dizem que é mais eficaz do que baixar um software de exploração de arquivos e instalar direto no aparelho. Eu basicamente quero acessar meu celular que está em minha WiFi e intalar .apks nele. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conecte o dispositivo ao computador (com a depuração está habilitado]a). Baixe e instale o SDK do Android no seu computador.

Uma vez que o SDK está instalado, inicie o Android SDK Manager (localizado na pasta program-files/android-sdks.) Marque 'Android SDK Tools Platform' e clique em "Instalar".

Uma vez que a instalação estiver concluída, localize o programa adb.exe (dentro program-files/android-sdks/platform-tools) e clique com o botão direito sobre ela, mantendo a tecla "Shift". Selecione "prompt de comando aberto aqui" e adb vai abrir uma nova janela. Este é o lugar onde você vai digitar todos os seus comandos.

Comece digitando 'adb devices' e na pressione'Enter'. Se você conectou o dispositivo com sucesso, ele será listado na janela adb. Se ele não estiver na lista, tente conectar o dispositivo a uma porta diferente e verifique se os drivers corretos instalados.

Uma vez adb reconhece o dispositivo, escreva'adb install' seguido do local do apk, incluindo o nome do arquivo e sua extensão .apk e Aperte 'Enter'.

Quando o processo estiver concluído, o aplicativo irá aparecer na sua lista de apps e estar pronto para usar.

ps: Caso queiram fazer a conexão via wi-fi pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
./adb.exe connect 192.168.2.143
connected to 192.168.2.143:5555

./adb.exe install -r xyz.apk
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/xyz.apk
```

Comment: Dante, sua solução exige que o aparelho esteja conectado ao computador. Eu acredito que ela não atenda à necessidade do OP, que especificou a instalação de APKs via rede wireless.

Comment: huuuuuuuum, mas então basta ele tentar fazer o processo só que com o celular conectado via wi-fi no notebook...o essencial é o software instalado

Comment: Talvez você possa elaborar um pouco entao sobre como 'conectar o celular via wi-fi no notebook'. Eu confesso que não entendi.

Comment: Conectando assim, por exemplo:
./adb.exe connect 192.168.2.143
connected to 192.168.2.143:5555

./adb.exe install -r xyz.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/xyz.apk

Comment: Perfeito, isso sim funcionaria. Talvez seja interessante inserir estas 2 linhas na sua resposta, para facilitar o entendimento tanto por parte do OP quanto de futuros visitantes.

Comment: muito bom, deu certinho :D queria votar a favor mas preciso de 15 pontos para isso :c, consegui instalar um fake_malware.apk aqui, agora é só ir direto a minha aplicação e voltar a testar. Obrigado!

Comment: @paccamicio, de nada cara ^^ Se conseguir os pontos depois vem cá e vota a favor.

Comment: @OnoSendai vou adicionar à minha resposta isso também, fica mais completa! Obrigado

Comment: @Dante, pode ter certeza que volto para votar a favor. ^^

Comment: @Dante como prometido, assim que consegui os pontos, voto a favor ^^

Comment: Opa @paccamicio, valeu cara! Sucesso em seu desenvolvimento!