# Como instalar/executar uma app assinada de forma a ver o log de erros?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um app e testo direto no celular (LGE API Level 16) .

Quando testo, executa normal. Mas quando gerei um apk assinado, e tento instalar esse apk no mesmo celular ele só diz: Aplicativo não instalado.

Isso aconteceu depois que adicionei no gradle a nível de módulo a linha:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

E no gradle a nivel de projeto:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

E adicionei o projeto no firebase

Estou meio que receoso desse app  nao executar nos celulares quando estiver na Google Play.

O minSdkVersion é 9.

A dúvida é:

Como instalar/executar uma app assinada de forma a ver o log de erros, para saber o motivo de ele não ter sido instalado.

Comment: Você está a instalar a app "assinada" via usb ou via Google Play?

Comment: eu passo o apk para a memória do celular para tentar instalar

Comment: Faça a instalação via AndroidStudio, só assim poderá ver algum log.

Comment: como é que faz via Android Studio?

Comment: Deu isso aqui: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: Bom. A pergunta você já resolveu. Então pode adicionar a resposta pra eu marcar como resolvida. Agora vou atrás de resolver essa outra mensagem rsrs

Comment: Consegui resolver também essa mensagem

Comment: Já que consegui resolver dê você mesmo a resposta.

Comment: Mas foi graças à sua resposta..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a instalação via AndroidStudio.

No menu do Android Studio escolha **build -> Edit Build Types...**.
Na janela apresentada seleccione a tab **Signing** e clique no sinal `+`.
Preencha os campos no lado direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seleccione a tab **Build Types** e escolha **release**.

No ComboBox **Signing Config** escolha **config**(ou o nome dado no passo anterior)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feche a janela.
Na borda esquerda do Android Studio clique em **Build Variantes**.
Na coluna **Build Variant** altere de **debug** para **relaese**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute a app como normalmente faz(icon com seta verde).

Comment: Ah ta! Beleza. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Bom. Graças ao comentário do amigo [ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral) consegui resolver o problema.

Instalei o app via o adb do Sdk do Android. Como?

Seguindo essa resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27141/54152):

Executando o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
adb install -r xyz.apk
```

Aí deu a seguinte mensagem:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Como se eu tinha gerado o apk assinado?

O que eu fiz então?

Removi o arquivo .apk e o arquivo .jks gerado anteriormente, porque eu estava só reaproveitando e recriei esses arquivos.

Executei novamente a instalação via adb novamente e finalmente instalou com sucesso a aplicação.

É isso.